# How to set day month and year values for a Date or DataAndTime object in Smalltalk (Pharo / Squeak)

Tags: date, smalltalk, pharo, squeak

I'm trying to find a a pre-defined method for objects of Class Date or Class DateAndTime, that allows me to create an new Date (or a new DateAndTime) by supplying three integers: one integer for the day of the month (1-31); one for the month (1 - 12); and a four-digit integer for the year.

( The closest I've found so far is Integer>>asYear )

Is there a method that can set all three parameters at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to create an instance of `Date` from three integers representing the `day`, `month` and `year` of said date.

When facing a question like this you can browse the class, `Date` in this case, and check its protocol for `instance creation` methods. In Pharo there are several methods in this category, but it is easy so see (I think) that `#year:month:day` looks like a good candidate. So, you can try it. Just evaluate the expression

```
Date year: 2015 month: 12 day: 31
```

and see what happens (you can inspect or print it to see the result).

You will also find `#newDay:month:year` as another good candidate. You could try it too. Or you could just see that it sends our previous message and thus it is just a synonymous (which is present for compatibility with other dialects that support the Smalltalk-80/ANSI specification).

Comment: That's exactly the sort of method I was looking for, thank you.  I'm currently working from Pharo 1.4 Update #14457, to match Pharo By Example.  It has no Date>>newDay:month:year: method, unfortunately.  My takeaway from this is that I'll start doing my exploring in a Pharo 4 image, and only follow the book in Pharo 1.4

Comment: Now I'm even more confused - the method isn't listed in the Browser in Pharo 1.4, but the object responds to it correctly, and I can find it.

Comment: Because year:month:day is a Class method, not an instance method.  Because it is used on the Class to create a new instance with the correct information.

Answer (score 0):

String>>asDate

allows for date-formatted Strings to be converted into Dates

e.g. (in a Workspace)

```
    aDateString := String new . " prints as '' "
    aDateString := '1984-11-03' . " prints as '1984-11-03' "
    aDate := Date new . " prints as 1 January 1901 "
    aDate := aDateString asDate . "prints as 3 November 1984"
```

The comment in the String>>asDate method states that "Many allowed forms, see Date>>#readFrom:"

Date>>readFrom: says

```
"Read a Date from the stream in any of the forms:  
<day> <month> <year>        (15 April 1982; 15-APR-82; 15.4.82; 15APR82)  
<month> <day> <year>        (April 15, 1982; 4/15/82)
<year>-<month>-<day>        (1982-04-15) (ISO8601)"
```

Also relevant: String>>asDateAndTime

n.b. a DateAndTime object is an exact instant in time.

Date, Year, Month, Week and Schedule are all subclasses of Class Timespan, so they all have a start moment, a duration, and an end moment.